# How to update object values in database when ModelState is invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, entity-framework-4.1

I am using Entity Framework 4.1 and MVC3. I have a form that is used to update my model properties. The properties have attributes for validation. The validation works fine and when executing an action, the ModelState contains all information about the validation errors.

Normally, when there are errors, data is not saved and the form with validation info is redisplayed to the user.

What I want to do is to save the valid properties and leave the invalid ones out. Client side validation works and invalid fields become red, so they can be changed and saved in the next request.

How can I achieve that? Has anyone done something similar in the past?

Comment: What do you mean by "leaving invalid ones out"? What do you expect to have in the database for invalid properties? Would you like to set corresponding columns to null? Or would you like to use the previous value (if the entity already exists in the database). Is it ok if the user does not correct the error and you are left with only partially filled rows?

Comment: I would like to update only those properties that have a valid state. I want to omit updating the ones that are invalid (so the current database value remains unchanged). It is OK if the user does not correct the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to disable validation (DbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled) and override DbContext.SaveChanges(). In the overriden method I would invoke DbContext.GetValidationErrors() which would return a list of invalid entites. Then I would detach these entites from the context and call base.SaveChanges(). After the call to SaveChanges has completed I would reattach invalid entities.